# Range() function change integers (values) in dictionary to objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, range, python-3.7

I want to have values as integers assigned to keys, but instead of it when I'm generating integers as values, I'm creating an object.

This is my code:

```
prices_for_letters = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, (i for i in range(1, 27)))
```

Actual result:

```
{'a': <generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022AB7EF6D68>, 
 'b': <generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022AB7EF6D68>
 ...}
```

Expected result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, ...}
```

Comment: Try: `dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))`

Comment: `range` isn't changing your integers into generator objects. the comprehension statement `(i for i in range(1,27))` returns a generator in python 3. So you're assigning the entire generator (if you iterate, you'll see it's a list of values from 1 to 26) to each key.

Comment: `d = {letter:i+1 for i,letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}` would also do it.

Comment: Integers *are* objects. *Everything* is an object. You wrote a generator expression, which is why you got a generator object instead of an integer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. EXPLANATION OF PROBLEM WITH YOUR CODE:

It appears you wanted to use a list comprehension but you ended up with, `(i for i in range(1, 27))`, and that produces a generator which only loads each item one by one during iteration instead of generating the whole list ahead of time. It is good for preserving memory, but that's not what you wanted. Therefore, you should use a list comprehension, as demonstrated below, for your second parameter.

```
>>> [i for i in range(1, 27)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

When you have fixed that as below, you will still not get what you want...

```
>>> prices_for_letters = dict.fromkeys(list(string.ascii_lowercase), [i for i in range(1, 27)])
>>> prices_for_letters
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
...
'w': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
'z': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]}
```

This is because the `dict.fromkeys()` method, as you used it, maps each item in the first parameter to the second parameter. In this case, the whole list gets assigned to each key.

That's not what you want, and that is why you must use zip as shown below:

```
>>> prices_for_letters = dict(zip(list(string.ascii_lowercase), [i for i in range(1, 27)]))
>>> prices_for_letters
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7,
'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14,
'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21,
'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26}
```

`zip` creates a mapping of items between lists and returns a list of tuples. When we convert a tuple to a dictionary explicitly using `dict(the_tuple)`, the first item of the tuple becomes the key, and the other item becomes the value. But, this is still not good enough; it is too much code. My proposed solution is below.

2. PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
>>> prices_for_letters = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
>>> prices_for_letters
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 
'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16, 'q': 17,
'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25,
'z': 26}
```

Comment: Thx for this intensive feedback! I was struggling with this subject for a whole day. :-)

Comment: Glad it helped :). Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` instead:

```
import string
prices_for_letters = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
print(prices_for_letters)
#{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 
# 'i': 9, 'h': 8, 'k': 11, 'j': 10, 'm': 13, 'l': 12, 
# 'o': 15, 'n': 14, 'q': 17, 'p': 16, 's': 19, 'r': 18, 
# 'u': 21, 't': 20, 'w': 23, 'v': 22, 'y': 25, 'x': 24, 'z': 26}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from string import ascii_lowercase

prices_for_letters = {ascii_lowercase[i]: i+1 for i in range(26)}
pprint(prices_for_letters)
```

**Output:**

```py
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3,
 'd': 4,
 'e': 5,
 'f': 6,
 'g': 7,
 'h': 8,
 'i': 9,
 'j': 10,
 'k': 11,
 'l': 12,
 'm': 13,
 'n': 14,
 'o': 15,
 'p': 16,
 'q': 17,
 'r': 18,
 's': 19,
 't': 20,
 'u': 21,
 'v': 22,
 'w': 23,
 'x': 24,
 'y': 25,
 'z': 26}
```